# Create a Server in Ubuntu 14 / 15 compatible with W7 / W10

Tags: networking, server, windows, samba

**Hello guys , i'm new in Linux** , i want setup a server in Linux, Which can check Access data base and the email with computers in LAN which use Windowns.

Its a bit dump, because Linux is Better With MySQL , PHP and Windows With Access, but i want do test.

I have another question :

1. What is the diference in Ubuntu Desktop and Server?
2. I can setup shared folders with Samba Between Ubuntu and W7 in LAN?
3. I can install Ubuntu v14 or v15 on PIII With 1Gb DDR? ( Only for Test)
4. I ​​can do a " pilot" on VirtualMachine?
5. I can administer the email with Thunderbird? Is so easy as Outlook?

Very thank for the help guys!

Comment: please check this it will be help you to deal with your issues    http://askubuntu.com/questions/729014/how-to-set-up-the-ubuntu-14-included-x-windowsxubuntu-mysql-php-apache/729015#729015

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to access your database from the other computer on your network, if that's what you're asking. Your servers will be running on your Ubuntu machine, and the other windows machines will have clients to access those servers.

For the other questions:

1. The main difference will be that by default, a server distribution will not have a desktop environment, so you will have to manipulate it with command lines.
   Server distribution will also have a smaller footprint in terms of needed resources.
2. Yes, you can.
3. Yes, you can.
4. I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can create a test VM to try your setup. You can also create VMs in Ubuntu (ie. with VirtualBox)
5. You can run a mail server on your Ubuntu machine, and access it with thunderbird on your windows machines. You can also install Thunderbird on your Ubuntu machine, if it has a Desktop environment.