# How To Set Up the Ubuntu 14.* Included X-Windows(xUbuntu) / MySql / PHP (Apache 2 ) In VMware

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, apache2, mysql, php

I had used Linux system for near decade , but now I need to use it again because I want to use more open resources and try to use like **DevOpe solutions** so that I hope I can give me some notices and remarks in this case.for my steps and ideas as following , I wish

> 1.To create and set Ubuntu 14.**
>   2.To create and set XUbuntu
>   3.To create and set MySql
>   4.To create and set MySql Workbench
>   5.To create and set Apache2 /PHP

PS: **I've done with all my steps**, and I will show how to do it in my answers,hopefully it can help someone who has the same problem with me ,by the way please let me know if you have any problems in my case.

Comment: I have a question, why not just *start* with Xubuntu 14.04, and then install MySQL, MySQL Workbench, etc. after the fact? Saves yourself two steps at once...

Comment: Hi@ThomasW.  Thanks for your comment , Sorry my English isn't very well, you mean I've pulled too much content in the one topic , or . please help me, how can I do , I have no idea, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it many times and all software is work on **VMware**, hopefully it is a great way to help someone who has the same problems like me, please follow my steps , it will assist you to handle all processes

**Step1 Ubuntu 14.**
Please download Ubuntu and use it in VM
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
like as picture

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Step2 XUbuntu (if you want x-Windows)**
And then you can setup x-windows

```
sudo apt-get install -y xfce4 xfce4-goodies      
sudo apt-get install xubutu-desktop
```

[image]
[image]

**PS: To set the network IP** 
[image]

**Step3 MySql**
[Reference URL](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/lamp/lamp-on-ubuntu-14-04)
MySQL

> Install and Configure

1. Install the `mysql-server` package:

   sudo apt-get install mysql-server
2. Choose a secure password when prompted.
3. Run `mysql_secure_installation`, a program that helps secure MySQL. You will be presented with the opportunity to change the MySQL root password, remove anonymous user accounts, disable root logins outside of localhost, and remove test databases:

   mysql_secure_installation

> Create a MySQL Database

1. Log into MySQL:

   mysql -u root -p
2. Enter MySQL’s root password, and you’ll be presented with a MySQL prompt.
3. Create a database and a user with permissions for it. In this example the databse is called `webdata`, the `userwebuser` and password `password`:

   create database webdata; 
   grant all on webdata.* to 'webuser' identified by 'password';
4. Exit MySQL:

   quit

> How to check SQL connect between Client /Server site. if you want to check please follow next content

1.Have to change file authorization

```
chmod –R 777 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
vi  /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

2.To replace IP address

```
#from      
#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1    
#to     
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

3.To change file authorization back

```
chmod –R 000 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

[image]

**Step 4 MySQL Workbench 6.3.6**
[Reference URL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads)
[image]
And then running mysql-workbench
[image]
And then restart your system
Finally to double check MySql server is okay with connection from client to server side
[image]

**Step 5 Apache2 /PHP**
[Reference URL](https://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-lamp-server-with-apache2-php5-mysql-on-14.04-lts)

> First we install MySQL 5 like this:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

> Installing Apache2

Apache2 is installed by default in ubuntu14.04, If not installed then install it. Apache2 is available as an Ubuntu package, therefore we can install it like this:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

[image]
Now direct your browser to http://127.0.0.1, and you should see the Apache2 placeholder page (It works!):
Apache's default document root is */var/www/html* on Ubuntu, and the configuration file is */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*. The configuration system is fully documented in /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz

> Installing PHP5

We can install PHP5 and the Apache PHP5 module as follows:

```
apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

We must restart Apache afterwards:

```
service apache2 restart
```

> 5 Testing PHP5 / Getting Details About Your PHP5 Installation

The document root of the default web site is */var/www/html*. We will now create a small PHP file ***(info.php)*** in that directory and call it in a browser. The file will display lots of useful details about our PHP installation, such as the installed PHP version.

```
vi /var/www/html/info.php

<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now we call that file in a browser (**e.g.http://127.0.0.1/info.php**):

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if my processes aren't clean ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add how to install Ubuntu 18.* setting a step up for the client
Step1:
[Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Step2:
To assign  *.iso to VM and then the system will be installed by  automatic

[Mandarin reference](https://www.sysgeek.cn/install-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)